# Android : Firebase dynamic link always goes to playstore URL even if the app is installed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to integrate Firebase dynamic link into Android app but the problem is that even if the app is installed the dynamic link is taking me to play store page to download the App from play store. 
I sent email with dynamic link. Then at Android smartphone, I opened the email and clicked the dynamic link, it goes to play store always..
Did anybody face the same problem and have solution for the same.

When I tested at https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/test
the dynamic link goes to the app well. Because the app was installed.

I added SHA-1, SHA-256 key to my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="io.chillingchat.android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/adv"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity
        android:name="io.chillingchat.android.view.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="io.chillingchat.android.view.AuthActivity">

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data
                android:host="chillingchat.io"
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <data
                android:host="chillingchat.io"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

```
actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
            // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) 
            // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
            .setUrl("https://chillingchat.page.link/in")
            // This must be true
            .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
            .setAndroidPackageName(
                    "io.chillingchat.android",
                    true, /* installIfNotAvailable */
                    "16"    /* minimumVersion */)
            .build();
```

Comment: Check the package name you are using in firebase and package name of your app. Make Sure they are same

Comment: @HemilKumbhani  It's same..

Comment: I am facing the same issue but only in one device, and not a specific model number, as the same model different device it works. in one of my testing device of motorola x4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solve this terrible problem.

In actionCodeSetting,

```
.setAndroidPackageName(
                "io.chillingchat.android",
                true, /* installIfNotAvailable */
                "16"    /* minimumVersion */)
```

change to

```
.setAndroidPackageName(
                "io.chillingchat.android",
                false, /* installIfNotAvailable */
                "16"    /* minimumVersion */)
```

but I don't know why change true to false the * installIfNotAvailable * option makes working..